# CRUDRepository findBy foreign key id causing exception: Unable to locate Attribute with the the given name [classroomId] on this ManagedType

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I am getting an exception when creating a custom findBy method by a foreign key.

Entity class:

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Thread {

  private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
  private String subject;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Classroom classroom;

  protected Thread() {}

  public Long getClassroomId() {
    return this.classroom.getId();
  }
}
```

ThreadRepository class:

```
public interface ThreadRepository extends CrudRepository<Thread, Long> {
  List<Thread> findByClassroomId(Long id);
}
```

I get the exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [classroomId] on this ManagedType [com.futurerprood.unicycleservice.entity.threads.Thread]
```

But the exception goes away if I remove the `getClassroomId()` in the `Thread` class. I have this function so that the json serialization will pick up only the classroom id instead of the whole classroom object in an endpoint response.

Why is this function causing the foreign key unable to be found?

Comment: You *might* be facing [this bug](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAJPA-890). A workaround could be to rename the repository method to `findByClassroom_id`. Haven't tried it though, can't guarantee it will work

Comment: Left a reply on that bug since it hasnt been fix/investigated by Spring

Answer (score 0):

**You can do one of the following:**

- Provide the query to the repository method

```
   @Query("select e from Thread t join t.classroom c where c.id = :id")
   List<Thread> findByClassroomId(Long id);
```

- Rename the repository method

```
   List<Event> findByClassroom_Id(Long id);
```

**Update**

**Explanation as to why these two are working**

- First, have a look at https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.4.3.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#d0e391 and understand how property traversal based on method name happens in Spring data JPA in order to generate the query and how ambiguity resolution is recommended.

1. In the first one, we tell spring data, it does not need to do property traversal to generate the JPA query as we are giving the query so it does not get any ambiguity.
2. In the second, as recommended in the reference, we are resolving the ambiguity for Spring Data JPA by telling it to go to Classroom object first. But as @crizzis pointed out under the question comment, Spring data should have treated it as ambiguity in the first place

Comment: thanks for those suggestions! However, I'd like to know why it's happening. Why does adding a getter for the foreign key disable it from being queried in the repository?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Does it answer your question?